# How to resolve SQL error in stored procedure

Tags: mariadb, stored-procedures

I'm using MariaDB 10.5.9, my stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`trainer`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `updateTrainee`(
      IN `_txtTrainee` TEXT,
      IN `_field` TEXT,
      IN `_data` VARCHAR(16)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'Adds or updates a field in the trainees table'
exitProc:BEGIN
#Procedure:       updateTrainee
#Parameters:      _txtTrainee Host name of trainee
#                 _field      Field to add or update
#                 _data       Data to add or update
#Notes:           Updates or adds trainee record
#History:         2021/07/30  Written by Simon Platten
      SET @SQL := CONCAT('INSERT INTO trainees (txtTrainee,?)',
                         ' VALUE (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE',
                         ' ?=VALUES(?)')";
      PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
      IF NOT (_field IS NULL AND _txtTrainee IS NULL AND _data IS NULL) THEN
            EXECUTE stmt USING _field, _txtTrainee, _data, _field, _field;
      END IF;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

When I call this with:

```
CALL updateTrainee('Simon', 'vcPD', '100');
```

I get an SQL error dialog up containing:

```
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax:
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
server version for the right syntax to use near
'?)VALUES(?,?)ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ?=VALUES(?)'
at line 1
```

Here is the code for the trainee table:

```
CREATE TABLE `trainees` (
      `txtTrainee` TEXT(65535) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Trainee host name' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
      `vcPD` VARCHAR(16) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Probability of Detection' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci',
      `intFA` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'False Alarm Rate',
      `intStartPoint` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Start Point',
      `intStopPoint` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Stop Point',
      `intGain` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Gain',
      `intTVG` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'TVG',
      PRIMARY KEY (`txtTrainee`(100)) USING BTREE
)
COMMENT='Table for storing trainee data'
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Only user-defined variables can be used as prepared statement parameters. So assign SP parameters to UDVs.

Comment: Please explain, I've done almost exactly the same in other procedures.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&rdbms2=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=cdef57d820d4af05bd8bdbc7c1d00e24

Comment: PS. 1st `?` in your dynSQL text is used as column name placeholder. This is not allowed. Use CONCAT() and insert the value into the variable text.

Comment: I did that with exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF NOT (_field IS NULL AND _txtTrainee IS NULL AND _data IS NULL) THEN
    SET @SQL := CONCAT('INSERT INTO trainees (txtTrainee,', _field, ')',
                       ' VALUE (?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE',
                       ' ', _field, '=VALUES(', _field, ')')";
    PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE stmt USING _txtTrainee, _data;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END IF;
```

Comment: That doesn't look right and is exactly why prepared statements exist, because dropping in the parameters with CONCAT will not wrap the data in quotes.  Using ? is a safer option.

Comment: @SPlatten Object names (column names in your case) cannot be parametrized. *will not wrap the data in quotes. Using ? is a safer option.* ??? 1) Quoting needed in SQL text and not needed for parameters values - they are provided during execution, not are inserted into before the execution. 2) Do you know that a quote char is NOT legal for object names quoting?

Comment: Thank you, it works!

Comment: @SPlatten I hope that `_field` value provided is "legal" (i.e. does not contain spaces, national chars, etc.). If not then you must add quoting backticks, i.e. not ```.. ', _field, ' ..``` but ```.. `', _field, '` ..```.

Answer (score 0):

First column names can't be replaced in prepared tatements.

second preparared statements need user defiend variables as parameters

the last point is a security risk, with the filed name or columnname that could be3 used for sql inejction, so you should have a whitelist for columnames like in te examle

> ```
> CREATE TABLE trainees (txtTrainee varchar(100), field1 int)
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE updateTrainee (_field varchar(50), _txtTrainee varchar(100), _data int)
> BEGIN
> #Procedure:  updateTrainee
> #Parameters: _txtTrainee Host name of trainee
> #            _field      Field to add or update
> #            _data       Data to add or update
> #Notes:      Updates or adds trainee record
> #History:    2021/07/30  Written by Simon Platten
>       DECLARE strSQL    TEXT;
>       sET @trainne := _txtTrainee;
>       sET @data := _data;
>       sET @field := _field;
>       IF EXISTS (sELECT 1 WHERE @field IN('field1','field2','field3')) then
>       SET strSQL = CONCAT('INSERT INTO trainees (txtTrainee,',_field,')',
>                           'VALUES(?,?)',
>                           'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ',_field,' = VALUES(',_field,')');
>       SET @SQL = strSQL;
>       
>       PREPARE stmt FROM @SQL;
>       EXECUTE stmt USING @trainne,@data;
>       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
>       end if;
> END
> ```

> ```
> call updateTrainee('field1','test1',1)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM trainees
> ```
>
> ```
> txtTrainee | field1
> :--------- | -----:
> test1      |      1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=bd5ff3eaa9ef84edce183df153d59af6)*